# Notepad ++ how to copy a string then add that to the beginning of a line until a similar string is reached?

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have a large txt file formatted something like this:

```
12345
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur 
adipiscing
--------
24680   
elit
sed
do
eiusmod
--------
76543
tempor
incididunt 
ut
```

... etc

Basically a 5 digit number follow by a random number of lines of text, then another 5 digit number and repeat etc...

What I would like to achieve is to add the correct five digit number to the start of every line. eg:

```
12345 Lorem
12345 ipsum
12345 dolor
12345 sit
12345 amet
12345 consectetur 
12345 adipiscing
--------  
24680 elit
24680 sed
24680 do
24680 eiusmod
--------
76543 tempor
76543 incididunt 
76543 ut
```

... etc

I'm really not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I started with the expression below but with "." as new line it highlights the whole file. Even if it did higligh only the section between digits I'm not sure exactly how to append the number to each line.

```
^(\d{5})(\r\n)(.*)(-{8})$
```

Comment: It seems to be something that should be done with a script (Perl, Python, AWK) rather than with Notepad++.

Comment: Are you limited to only using NotePad++ for this?  Something like Java or .NET seems more appropriate to me.  And if you solve this in Notepad++ I believe you will need a macro.

Comment: or a better editor like vim

Comment: Is this a once in a lifetime thing or are going to do this often? If often: use a scripting language. If once and never again: how many lines are in the file?

Comment: There is a two step solution that is semi-manual: you will have to either automate it with a macro, or press Replace All until no replacement takes place at Step 2. 1) `^(\d+)\s*\R+(?!\1)` -> `"\1 "` (and press Replace All once), 2) `^((\d+).*\R+)(?!\2|-{5}|\z)` --> `"\1\2 "` (and press Replace All multiple times until no match is found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a two step solution that is semi-manual: you will have to either automate it with a macro, or press *Replace All* until no replacement takes place at Step 2.

Step 1.

Use the following regex

```
^(\d+)\s*\R+(?!\1)
```

And replace with `\1` . Press *Replace All* once.

Step 2.

Use

```
^((\d+).*\R+)(?!\2|-{5}|\z)
```

And replace with `\1\2` . Press *Replace All* multiple times until no match is found.